# Ruby on Rails: Invert checkbox check/uncheck value on submit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, form-for

I have a website, where you can register for some events I called talks. After the registration the "guest" gets a confirmation email with a generated unsubscribe link.
The link opens a form with all the events listed that the guest registered for.

Now to unsubscribe from an event the guest has to *uncheck* the checkbox of the event. But I want it inverted so that they have to *check* the event to unsubscribe from it.

---

The models

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_may :talks
end

class Talk < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_may :guests
end
```

---

The unsubscribe form

```
<%= form_for @guest do |f| %>
  <% f.collection_check_boxes :talk_ids, @guest.talks, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box %>
    <%= b.object.name %>
  <% end %>

<input type="submit" value="Unsubscribe">
<% end %>
```

---

The update function after submitting

```
def update_talks
  @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  if @guest.update(guest_params)
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Failed"
  end
end
```

I couldn't find a solution so I hope you guys can tell me how to invert the checkbox?

Comment: you can show all the checkbox as an unchecked, and then you have to change the default value of checkbox sends as params, like for checked you have to send 0 instead of 1, or false instead of true, this will help you https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

Comment: But because I use collection_check_boxes I can't give my b.check_box arguments, except one for extra_html_options. How can I set the checked_value for collection_check_boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Been a while, but I just ran into a similar issue where in some cases it is better for the interface to understand if the checked checkbox sets the boolean in the database to false.

This is the Rails 7 check_box method [form_helper.rb](https://github.com/ghiculescu/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb):

```
def check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
  Tags::CheckBox.new(object_name, method, self, checked_value, unchecked_value, options).render
end
```

So you only need to change the checked_value to 0, the unchecked_value to 1 and toggle the checked option. In my case (imagine "method" is the boolean in the database:

```
= f.check_box :method, { checked: !f.object.method? }, '0', '1'
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a very beginner in Rails, but maybe it'll be better if the checkboxes come already checked

Comment: They already come checked. But its weird to uncheck them and press the unsubscribe button, thats why I want it inverted.